# What is the proper way to configure a Maven project to output a classifier JAR without warnings and have Javadoc and Sources plugins work?

Tags: java, maven, jar, maven-javadoc-plugin, maven-source-plugin

I have [a Maven project](https://github.com/OddSource/ifaddrs4u/tree/main/ifaddrs4j) with Java sources that generates one JAR file and that JAR file has a classifier (more on why in a separate section below). As described by others [in this bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MINSTALL-151), this causes an error:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:3.1.1:install (default-install) on project <project_name>: NoFileAssignedException:
The packaging plugin for this project did not assign a main file to the project but it has attachments. Change packaging to 'pom'. -> [Help 1]
```

A [comment](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MINSTALL-151?focusedCommentId=17704498&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-17704498) on this bug led me to the [`<allowIncompleteProjects>`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-mojo.html#allowincompleteprojects) configuration, an "escape hatch" that is considered to "resolve" this bug, but the explanation for this tag makes me concerned that this is not "the right way":

> By default, such projects are forbidden and Mojo will fail to process them. ... In the majority of cases, what user really wants here is a project with "pom" packaging and some classified artifact attached (typical example is some assembly being packaged and attached with classifier).

It sure sounds like I really need `<packaging>pom</packaging>` instead of `<packaging>jar</packaging>`. So I tried that. Understandably, I had to jump through some extra hoops to configure executions for resources, compiler, and surefire plugins. However, using `pom` appears to completely the disable javadoc and source plugins: I cannot generate a sources JAR or a javadoc JAR and I cannot even generate a javadoc report in `<reporting>` with `mvn site`. The Javadoc JAR attempt, at least, gives me some feedback, though I do not understand it:

> Not executing Javadoc as the project is not a Java classpath-capable package

But the site report just *appears to work* and then does nothing (no output or content generated):

> [INFO] configuring report plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:3.6.0
> [INFO] 1 report configured for maven-javadoc-plugin:3.6.0: javadoc-no-fork
> [INFO] Rendering site with default locale English (en)

Those two lines are identical to the two lines on a separate `jar` project whose Javadoc works correctly. That project, however, has additional output below that, which is missing from this project's output:

> [INFO] configuring report plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:3.6.0
> [INFO] 1 report configured for maven-javadoc-plugin:3.6.0: javadoc-no-fork
> [INFO] Rendering site with default locale English (en)
> ...
> [INFO] Generating "Javadoc" report       --- maven-javadoc-plugin:3.6.0:javadoc-no-fork
> [INFO] Configuration changed, re-generating javadoc.
> [INFO]
> Loading source files for package io.oddsource.java.maven.profile...
> ...

It appears that the creators of the Javadoc and Source plugins have intentionally crippled these plugins for `pom` projects and my only option is `jar` with `<allowIncompleteProjects>`, but maybe I'm doing something wrong. Is there a better way?

As of publishing this, the current commit hash for my project is [f53ab7a8](https://github.com/OddSource/ifaddrs4u/tree/f53ab7a8292f116d1ef3ad149913a199fd17a74d/ifaddrs4j). I link specifically to that commit because that's the current `pom` version of the `pom.xml` that won't build Javadoc or Source JARs, and I'm probably going to switch back to `jar` just to get it to work for now.

**A Note on Why the Classifier**

This project includes C++ JNI code that gets compiled into a shared library and bundled in the JAR, but that makes the JAR platform-dependent. So I'm adding a platform-identifying classifier to the JAR file, and I'll compile and release this from multiple machines to have multiple JARs with different platform classifiers. I also plan on eventually creating a JAR with classifier `uber` (or similar) that contains multiple platforms in one JAR.

Comment: Why not use one top pom project with maven modules (sub-projects in subdirectories with their own poms)?

Comment: I thought about that, but it would be rather an abuse of that pattern, too, and isn't really fitting. I don't have any "sub-modules." The code isn't different from one platform to the next. I compile all the same files for every platform, they just have to be compiled and linked on target platforms.

Comment: The javadoc and source plugin do not make sense for a packaging `pom` because a module which is packaging `pom` does not contain any source code... that's the reason. Based on what I can see in that project I would suggest to make a clear separation of concern. One part Java and one part Cpp with. CMake and don't mix them into a single module.. Also why changed the default directory layout?